# Having to click twice on an autocomplete suggestion to populate on to the text field

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm able to populate all the required suggestions using typeahead.js
The problem is that i'm having to double click the autocomplete suggestion for it to populate into the text field. I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working on a single click.

Initialising typeahead with bloodhound:

```
       var titlesOnlyHound = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: titlesOnly
        });
       $('#titles').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true, /* Enable substring highlighting */
            minLength: 1  /*Specify minimum characters required for showing suggestions */

        },
        {
            name: 'titlesOnly',
            source: titlesOnlyHound,
            limit: 5,
            templates: {
                empty: [
                    '<div class="empty-message">No matching ideas found!</div>'
                ]
            }
        });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="bloodhound">
 <label for="autocomplete-input">Email address</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" id="titles" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Comment: check documentation it might be useful: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md OR http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/